# Getting an array based on data on another column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing vba code that fills a table of this form, given a set of data as below:

In the table i'm interested in getting maximum and minimum values over each day, Lastrow is the last row on the data table, and Año, Mes, Dia my current Year/Month/Day, which references where the values will be pasted in the table.

This is inside a couple of for loops which iterate through each present date on the data table, inside the for cycles I initialize variables and code goes as follows:

```
For Dia=1 to 31

    Cuenta = Sht.Range("C2", "C" & Lastrow).Find(DateSerial(Año, Mes, Dia)).Row           
    s = 0
    max = 0
    min = 0
    While Sht.Range("C" & Cuenta).Value = DateSerial(Año, Mes, Dia)

        'this counter is for how much data I'm averaging over

        s = s + 1  

        'Store the first data for the day
        If s = 1 Then
            max = Sht.Range("B" & Cuenta).Value
            min = Sht.Range("B" & Cuenta).Value
        End If

        'if another data piece is bigger or smaller than currently stored max or min, replace it

        If Sht.Range("B" & Cuenta).Value >= max Then
            max = Sht.Range("B" & Cuenta).Value
        End If

        If Sht.Range("B" & Cuenta).Value <= min Then
            min = Sht.Range("B" & Cuenta).Value
        End If

        Md = Md + Sht.Range("B" & Cuenta).Value

        'this counter is to move through data for each day starting on the first appearence of said date

        Cuenta = Cuenta + 1

    Wend

    Md = Md / s

    WS.Cells(Dia + 2, 3 * (Mes - 1) + 2) = min
    WS.Cells(Dia + 2, 3 * (Mes - 1) + 3) = Md
    WS.Cells(Dia + 2, 3 * (Mes - 1) + 4) = max

Next Dia
```

The thing is, my code works on all values but the first day of the first month, Idk why but data for day 1 doesn't take into account the first value for the month, either way, I'm sure there's an easier way of taking max or min values out of a data table, given an apearance of some data on another column using VBA.

BTW: Even though the table reads ene-17 as the first Date entry, thing thad would break my code, it's really 01-01-2017, It's just formatted differently

[image: Table]

[image: Data example]

Comment: I would suggest a totally different approach. In the VBA window, go to Tools->references and add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX data Objects 6.1 Library. This will allow you to run SQL statements against an Excel table so that you can take advantage of the power of the SQL language. Are you familiar with this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a totally different approach. In the VBA window, go to Tools->references and add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX data Objects 6.1 Library. This will allow you to run SQL statements against an Excel table so that you can take advantage of the power of the SQL language. This a code sample. You must write however the SQL query that fits your needs:

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset

sWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & 
sWorkbookName & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX = 1"""

sSheet="myDataSheet"
oConn.Open connString
'just an example of SQL, you have to customize it
sSQL = "SELECT [FIELD1], [FIELD2] FROM [" & sSheet & "$] " & " WHERE 
[FIELD1] =(SELECT MAX([FIELD1]) FROM [" & sSheet2 & "$]) ORDER BY [FIELD2] DESC"

rs.Open sSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

'dump results on a temporary sheet 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tmp_sheet").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
oConn.Close
```